# CakePHP $this->model->query

Tags: mysql, cakephp-1.3

I am trying to run following code and getting error only if I use not condition in where clause. I know I should use cake's save method but because of some sort of reason I have to use $this->model->query.

```
$this->Model->query("insert into students values ($department_id,$class_id) where depid <> $department_id and classid <> $class_id");
```

I am getting error as follows:

```
SQL Error: 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where tagid <> 1 and contactid <> 32' at line 1 [CORE\cake\libs\model\datasources\dbo_source.php, line 681]


Query: insert into students values(3,2) where depid <> 3 and classid <> 2
```

I tried putting depid!=3 and not depid=3 but nothing is working through CakePHP, however, <> works fine if I use directly in MySql. Don't know where is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The INSERT expression has no WHERE CLAUSE. [Read the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html).